# Why is my image rotated 45 degrees to the right on Safari, but not on other browsers?

Tags: html, css

OS: macOS

Browsers: tested on Safari macOS and iPadOS (both don't properly display it), and Firefox macOS (Works).

Relevant code:

```html
<div id="pictures-body">

    <ul>
        <li><img class="pictures-img" src="{% static '/images/cotton_bleh.JPG' %}"></li>
        <li><img class="pictures-img" src="{% static '/images/cotton_smiling.JPG' %}"></li>
        <li><img class="pictures-img" src="{% static '/images/cotton0.JPG' %}"></li>
        <li><img class="pictures-img" src="{% static '/images/cotton1.jpg' %}"></li>
        <li><img class="pictures-img" src="{% static '/images/cotton2.JPG' %}"></li>
        <li><img class="pictures-img" src="{% static '/images/cotton3.JPG' %}"></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

```css
.pictures-img {
    width: 5rem;
}
```

Screenshot (Safari)

[image]

Screenshot (Firefox)

[image]

Comment: Where is the actual CSS ? Show us how it is rotated please ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, that's it. That's the actual CSS code. It's not supposed to be rotated 45 degrees to the right. It's supposed to look normal because I didn't write code to make it rotate.

Comment: FYI, that’s 90 degrees what you have in your screenshots there, not 45.